# Is it better to quote the content of an article or just provide a link?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Guidelines for linking to external sites](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226/guidelines-for-linking-to-external-sites)

I just answered this [question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/4837/cracks-on-exterior-walls-are-they-serious-and-can-i-fix-them-myself) by providing a link to an article that might help the asker, and quoting a large chunk of the article (nearly the entire thing). Is this the proper way to handle a case like this, or should I have just provided the link?

Comment: Related: [Guidelines for linking to external sites](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/q/226/22), especially [this answer](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/226/guidelines-for-linking-to-external-sites/228#228)